# get value from jquery ajax response without setting async false

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, jquery-forms-plugin

I'm using jquery form plugin to submit data to server. Before submitting I'm running server side validation via ajax. so the structure is

```
function validateForm(formData, jqForm, options){
   var check = true; //have to set check to false to avoid form submit

   ....
   looping through form elements and putting values in to data array here
   ....

   function sendData(callback){

      $.ajax({
         url:'validate.php',
         data:data,
         dataType:'json',
         //async:false,  if I uncomment this, code works as I want
         success:callback
      });

   }

   function processForm(response){
      $.each(response,function(i,res){
        //if validation is fail I'm setting check = false here
      });
   }

   sendData(processForm);

   return check;

})
```

Since I saw setting async to false is not good practice, how can I set the check value to false using callbacks?

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to return the data. Do whatever work needs doing inside the callback (or in functions you call from it).

Comment: Replace "//if validation is fail I'm setting check = false here" with "Doing whatever you want to do if check is false"

Comment: I need to return false from this function if validation fails, so jquery form plugin blocks submit.

Comment: You have to return false either way, then restart if it the request comes back with OK. It seems pretty pointless though - using JS for validation saves the user time by avoiding a server round trip. If you're going to add an extra server round trip then you're being couterproductive.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the jQuery [`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) function? You can cancel submission where validation fails by calling `.preventDefault()`.

Example jQuery:

```
<script>

$("form").submit(function() {
  if ($("input:first").val() == "correct") {
    $("span").text("Validated...").show();
    return true;
  }
  $("span").text("Not valid!").show().fadeOut(1000);
  return false;
});

</script>
```

You could do your validation and submission in two phases - validate first, then use submit in an `OnAJAXSuccess` handler.

Comment: I'm using jQuery form plugin to submit data. [link](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/)